# "The pydev nature is not configured on the project" while adding a new Python module in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I get the **"The pydev nature is not configured on the project"** error while adding a new Python module in Eclipse.

Any ideas how to fix it? How to configure the pydev nature?

My configuration:

- Mac OS X 10.9.
- Eclipse SDK Version: 4.3.1 Build id: M20130911-1000
- PyDev for Eclipse 2.8.2.2013090511

.project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
        <name>myproject</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.python.pydev.PyDevBuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
                <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
        </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution for this problem is to uninstall PyDev and install it again. To do so:

1. Open Eclipse.
2. Go to "Help — Install New Software..."
3. Click "What is already installed?"
4. Select "PyDev for Eclipse" and press Uninstall...
5. Go through all dialogs and repeat these steps to install PyDev again.